# AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool not working in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, ios7

My app has functionality where it takes a recorded video and inserts animations on top of it. When the app was running iOS 6 this worked flawlessly. When I updated to iOS 7 it stopped working, without any compiler warnings or indications why. It still goes through the same motions as before and gives me an exported video, it just doesn't have any of the animations on top of it like it used to and I have no idea why.

Comment: you found a solution since?

Comment: The issue I was having was that they made a change that requires the animation's removedOnCompletion property to be set to "NO" in order for the animations to appear in the video. I added that to all of my animations and it worked like a charm!

Comment: okay thanks however I believe you had to set it to NO also with iOS6. maybe only a bug allowed it to work nonetheless. My problem is all animation on position and bounds return smaller images. than when playing in a synchronizedLayer

Comment: it was probably a bug that they fixed, yeah, because I didn't have them set to remove on iOS6. I wish I could help you with that problem but don't know how, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Define the `beginTime` of the Animation:

```
myAnimation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero
```